# Finding unused combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is a fast way to find combinations that aren't present in an array yet?

E.g, I have list of points: `[1, 2, 4, 9]`

And I have a list of connections `[[1,2], [1,4], [1,9], [2,4], [4,9]]`

So the missing connection in this list is `[2,9]`.  As there is one requirement: **every integer  must be connected to a bigger integer**.

```
var points = [1, 2, 4, 9];
var connections = [[1,2], [1,4], [1,9], [2,4], [4,9]];

var missing = [];
for(i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
  for(j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++){
    var found = false;
    for(var a = 0; a < connections.length; a++){
        if(connections[a][0] == points[i] && connections[a][1] == points[j]){
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found) missing.push([points[i], points[j]]);
  }
}

console.log(missing);
```

The above code works, but the amount of for loops makes me think it is reasonably slow. Is there any faster way to do this? View [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47a7t42s/1/)

Comment: Is your data guaranteed to be sorted or not?

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi no, the list of connections is not sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` method in order to generate all the combination of two elements.Then the only thing that will remain is to get the difference from two arrays.

For this, you can use `filter` method which accepts a `callback` method.

```js
var points = [1, 2, 4, 9];
points=points.sort();
var connections = [[1,2], [1,4], [1,9], [2,4], [4,9]];
var combinations = points.reduce(function(arr,elem,i){
      for(j=i+1;j<points.length;j++)
        arr.push([elem,points[j]]);
      return arr; 
},[]);
var diff=combinations.filter(function(elem,i){
   return connections.find(a=>a[0]==elem[0] && a[1]==elem[1])==undefined;
});
console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 2):

By sorting the array, you can do it with 2 nests. Sorting takes O(n log n), and the loops are basically O(n ^ 2).

```
var points = [1, 2, 4, 9];
var connections = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 4],
  [1, 9],
  [2, 4],
  [4, 9]
];

connections.sort();

var missing = [];
var currentIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
    if (connections[currentIndex][0] == points[i] && connections[currentIndex][1] == points[j]) {
      currentIndex++;
    } else {
      missing.push([points[i], points[j]]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(missing);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate only the outer loop until length - 2 and use a hash table for inserted `connections`. The sort order of `connections` does not matter.

```js
var points = [1, 2, 4, 9],
    connections = [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 9], [2, 4], [4, 9]],
    missing = [],
    i, j,
    pair,
    connected = Object.create(null);

connections.forEach(function (a) {
    connected[a.join()] = true;
});

for (i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
        pair = [points[i], points[j]];
        connected[pair.join()] || missing.push(pair);
    }
}

console.log(missing);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```